# what is the advantage of creating read only instance of db object over declaring it inside using block?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am creating db objects in my controllers which are being used at around hundred places and we have two ways of creating database context object:

First:

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    var result = db.GetUsere();
    ...
}

using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    var result1 = db.GetUserRoles();
    ...
}
```

Second:

```
private readonly MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
var result = db.GetUsere();
var result1 = db.GetUserRoles();
```

Here in the first case we have to create the db object each time we want to use it while in the second case only a single object will do the task.

So is there any specific advantage of using one over the other?

Is there a way to dispose the singleton db object when my controller is disposed which I have created on the controller initialization?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: If first case your dbContext gets disposed after execution comes out from using block, in second case you have to dispose manually

Comment: First case disposed the object, second one doesn't. This means that any unamanged resources will not be released, and start to leak.

Comment: You could override `IDisposable.Displose()` on the controller class to manually dispose the db object.  But as the answers indicate the `using` statement is considered the best practice / preferred form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case you have to dispose your context manually. Using the context inside a "using" block, guarantees it will be disposed:

> The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use using if you want all the resources that the context controls to be disposed at the end of the block. When you use using, the compiler automatically creates a try/finally block and calls dispose in the finally block.

[Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)

Also, using your context inside a using block, is considered a "standard". Have to manually manage your objects and know when to dispose them is a overwork that you definitely don't need. Let .Net do that for you.

Comment: The `using` statement does not directly have anything to do with the Garbage Collector.  Even if you don't dispose of the context it will still be collected by the GC at some point and likely the resources that are held will be disposed of then.  It's a matter of disposing resource as soon as possible versus waiting until the GC decides to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx) is a standard way of disposing the objects. So as others have commented in your first case dbContext is disposed after execution is completed and in your second case you have to manually dispose it.

From [ASP.NET MVC Tip #34 – Dispose of Your DataContext (or Don’t)](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t)

> The most important consequence of calling the DataContext.Dispose()
>   method is that any open connections associated with the DataContext
>   get closed. This might seem really important, but it’s not. The reason
>   that it is not important is that the DataContext class already manages
>   its connections. By default, the DataContext class opens and closes a
>   connection automatically.
>
> ...
>
> Most often, when you call the Dispose() method on the DataContext
>   object, any database connection associated with the DataContext object
>   is already closed. The DataContext object has closed the database
>   connection right after executing the database query. So, the Dispose()
>   method really doesn't have anything to do.

Comment: Is there a way to dispose the singleton db object when my controller is disposed which I have created on the controller initialization?

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd option, which is "the best of both worlds". You keep a single instance of your context with gets automatically disposed, but make multiple calls against it.

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    var result = db.GetUsere();
    var result1 = db.GetUserRoles();
    ...
}
```